# Custom UITableViewCell image doesn't appear in the first row

Tags: uitableview, uiimageview

I am facing this very weird problem, I have created a custom UITableViewCell on which I have a UIImageView on the left and on the right I have two UILabel.

When I run the program, I see all the image and the label appears on the table.

I have total of 5 rows that needs to be displayed

The only problem is the image starts displaying from the row 2 and goes upto row 6 where as the labels get displayed from row 1 to row 5.

Custom UITableViewCell .h file

```
@interface ProductViewCell : UITableViewCell {
 IBOutlet UILabel *titleLabel;
 IBOutlet UILabel *detailLabel;
 IBOutlet UIImageView *imageView;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) UILabel *titleLabel; 
@property (nonatomic, retain) UILabel *detailLabel;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIImageView *imageView;
```

And the UITableViewController that uses this is

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:
       (NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    ProductViewCell *cell = (ProductViewCell*)[tableView 
          dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {

          NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] 
                           loadNibNamed:@"ProductViewCell" owner:self options:nil];
  for(id currentObject in topLevelObjects){
   if([currentObject isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]]){
    cell = (ProductViewCell *) currentObject;
    break;
     }
   }
   }

 NSDictionary *dictionary = [self.tableDataSource objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

 cell.titleLabel.text = [dictionary objectForKey:@"name"];
 cell.detailLabel.text = @"";
 cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:
           [NSURL URLWithString: [dictionary objectForKey:@"imageUrl"]]]]; 
 return cell;


}
```

Comment: Hi Aaron, added the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem by doing this in my tableViewController

-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return 120.0; //returns floating point which will be used for a cell row height at specified row index
}

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it has something to do with the fact that imageView shadows the UITableViewCell definition. I think that row 6 would be displayed only if your tableView:numberOfRowsInSection: returns 6. It also might be something stupid, like the contents of the tableDataSource ;)

Comment: No, the numberOfRowsInsection do return 5, and tableDataSource is also fine, mine suspect is it has to do with the content not fitting in the cell properly. I have been trying to increase the height of the row and things like that but it isn't helping me.

Comment: Check with IB that you don't have a rogue UIImageView in your custom cell. And check the dimensions and position of the UIImageView in general. It's really weird.